# Functional component is not Re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, components

> Here is my code for calling the component
> When **is_new** becomes true this component got called but I need to recall the component when **errors** comes so I make the **reload** state true at that time but the component didn't call. I need to pass the error to that component after response.

```
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);


api
    .addleads(jsonToFormData(data, taskStates))
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 201 || response.status === 200) {
        if (response.data.data) {
          updatedCitiesAreas(response.data.data);
        }
        setLoading(false);
        setExistingClientform(existingclientInitial);
        setClients({
          column: "",
          value: "",
        });
        toastr["success"]("Lead Added Successfully!");
        setErrors([]);
       
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setLoading(false);

      if (error.response.data.errors) {
        setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
        setReload(true);
      }

    });


{state.is_new || reload ? (
                  <AddClientDetails
                    status="searchClient"
                    loader
                    clientForm={clientCheck}
                    errors={errors}
                    leadid={props.leadid}
                    numberStatus={numberStatus}
                  />
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
```

[Following is response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PqW1.png)

Comment: can you try to print a simple div with text instead of your component? maybe you have some problems with your component. check if that works, also print reload to console to see if you got the correct value. let me know when you are done so we can check it together

Comment: i had call the other Empty component with same logic. it was working. 
But its not work with this component.
what should i check ? @OzanMudul

Comment: since I don't know your component, I can tell much. Something must be wrong in your component that prevents it to be rendered

Comment: @OzanMudul Initially it renders good. but when props got changed. It didn't render.
may i send you the component ?

Comment: of course, probably something broke the component, we will fix that and it will be rendered again, we just need to find it

Comment: Where Do i send you the code ?

Comment: can you put it in a https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-keldysh-yp8gr?file=/src/AddClientDetails.js

Comment: ouch, that's a huge component. I strongly suggest you to put null checks and divide your components into a few, reusable ones. For now though, try to comment all your jsx then try to check which guy gives you the trouble. Also anything on console log that throws error, it can help the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just trace the child component and find why my component was prevented from re-render.

I put my props.error in child's useEffect Dependency error and the problem got solved.
When error comes. My useEffect got called and I set my errors there.